# No data qrcode image pass to URL after Ajax function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, qr-code

I want to pass data via url using ajax, the result is that no data is captured by the post method.

```
(function() {
  var qr = new QRious({
    element: document.getElementById('qr'),
    size: 200,
    value: 'https://github.com/ddsfdf'
  });
  var img = qr.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
  var img_data = img.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");

  $.ajax({
    'type': 'post',

    'url': '<?php echo base_url('dasboard/qrcode'); ?>',
    data: {

      'img': img_data
    },
    success: function(response) {

    }
  });
})();
```

and this is the code in the controller:

```
 $imagedata  = base64_decode($_POST['img']);
 $filename   = $id;
 $file_name  = './saveimageQR/' . $filename . '.png';
 file_put_contents($file_name, $imagedata);
```

i get result Undefined index:img which means no data sent,please help me Thank You.

Comment: Have you tried to debug this using your browser's Developer Tools? That's the place to start looking for clues

Comment: Code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/z34ug9bn/ (if you inspect the POST request you can see the data). Try `var_dump($_POST);` to find out what is sent.

Comment: I try `var_dump($_POST);` and I don't see the data.

Comment: Maybe you somehow have two different requests to the same endpoint. Again, use your browser tools to do some proper debugging

Comment: I tried to check using the browser's Developer Tools and got the error `message Error: Promised response from onMessage listener went out of scope index.js:29:93532`
what does it mean?

Comment: Well, firstly, to help us out, which line of your code is line 29 from index.js? Have you shown it in your question?

Comment: sorry after I checked again the error I got was `POST http://localhost:8080/dasboard/qrcode   [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 83ms]`

Comment: Ok thanks. 500 Internal Server Error is a generic error message informing you that the server crashed while processing the request. Beyond that, it's (intentionally) meaningless, and is of very little use for debugging. You need to check the error logs on the server to try and find the underlying exception message. Once you've got that, you stand a chance of identifying the problem.